# Find all the non- isomorphic forests with five vertices and two or more components.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Find all the non- isomorphic forests with five vertices and two or more components.

-I understand the concept of this question and have drawn out several graphs fitting these constraints, although I know there must be an equation that I can plug vertices and component values into to get the answer. The only formula I know from this chapter in my book that was remotely similar was Cayley's theorem which proved to be no help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The numbers are small enough that I’d do this one by brute force. There is one forest with $5$ components and one with $4$. There are three with $3$ components, and it’s not hard to find the ones with $2$ components, either.

Comment: I understand i was just worried about missing a possibility, how do you know that these are all the possible graphs? Is there a way to check?
Also, for the case with 4 components it looks as if you are not counting the vertices as unique, meaning the one connection between two vertices (say 1 and 2) is the same as all independent except a connection between say 3 and 4. Is that the correct way to approach all cases.?

Comment: Mostly just by being careful. For instance, there are two trees on $3$ vertices and only one on $2$ vertices, so there must be two forests that have a tree with $3$ and another tree with $2$ vertices. The same kind of analysis on a $4$-$1$ split just requires making sure that I find all of the $4$-vertex trees.

Comment: I edited my comment above yours with additional questions.

Comment: As I read the problem statement, the vertices are unlabelled, so a forest with $4$ components is simply three isolated vertices and a $K_2$.

Comment: Okay thanks that sounds good, does 7 sound about right for the 2 component case, just making sure i didn't miss anything.
(12 in total)

Comment: I don’t get that many. There are two that split $3$-$2$, and I see only two with a $4$-$1$ split: the tree on $4$ vertices is either a path of length $3$ or a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) with $3$ leaves.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/3O4KTlR) This is what I got for the 2 components. Disregard the numbering. Looking at it now though I feel I missed some still.

Comment: In the lefthand column the first and fourth examples aren’t forests, because the larger component isn’t a tree; the same goes for both graphs in the second column. The second, third, and fifth examples are the same. Thus, you’ve actually found just one. The other has an isolated vertex and a star graph with three leaves.

Comment: I see,makes perfect sense. Are those the only two permitable examples for 2 components?

Comment: There are two for the $3$-$2$ split and these two for the $4$-$1$ split.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't visualize the 3-2 example, I only found one?

Comment: Sorry, you’re right: I was thinking of rooted trees instead of just trees. That makes altogether three forests with $2$ components.

Comment: Okay great I think i understand it now, thanks for all the help.

Comment: You’re welcome.